# need help for database modelling in rails and controller's behaviors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, controllers

I'm new on rails and need people to give me some  explications about rails
I wanna create an startups list app.
Startup can have many categories and categories can have many startups. I've used nifty scaffold to generate startups and categories. this is my model file  for startups:

```
  class Annuaire < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :slogan, :description, :url, :email, :telephone, :image, :cp, :ville, :pays
 belongs_to :categorie
 end
```

the folow is for categories

`class Categorie < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description
   has_many :annuaires, dependent: :destroy
end`

I also add an foreign key , is that enough? when i buid my database model on paper i find that i need a third table which make association between  categories and startups. He will just got an ID and two foreign key , one for categories and one for startups. Could you please tell me if i'm on good way and give me a good advice about that work?
I also try to modify startup form . I add a select tag which will get all categories name from categorie table and show it to allow select by user :

```
<%= form_for @annuaire  do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_messages %>
      <p>
        <%= f.label :name %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <%= f.label :slogan %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :slogan %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <%= select_tag "categorie", options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, "id", "name") %>
      </p>
```

It dont work, i got the folowwing issue:

```
undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #12):
9
10
11
12
13
14
15

       <%= f.text_field :slogan %>
     </p>
     <p>
       <%= select_tag "categorie", options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, "id", "name") %>
     </p>
     <p>
       <%= f.label :description %><br />
```

Can someone help me please? sorry for my english, i'm french 
love the way rails is but i'm alone and it is little bit hard to understand all rails methods

Answer (score 0):

What does `@categories` contain? Did you assign anything to it in your controller?

In Ruby, the first instance of `@foo` will cause a @foo to exist, and give it a `nil` value, if no `@foo` existed before. So the downstream error, if the code then calls `@foo.map`, is not "foo does not exist", but "nil has no method map".

Comment: @categories contain categories.all but this is in categorie controller, in categorie folder , may be the startup form couln't find categorie controller?

Comment: Post your controller code. (And you may consider finding a local users group to get over these learning issues.)